# Prestashop - Image Upload / Options in admin to manage those images

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

Friends, I am beginner in Prestashop and I have to sort out an issue. Any help would be appreciated.

I have to create functionality where I can upload images from admin panel and to manage those images(Edit/Delete). And after that I have to show those images on frontend.

Now, the problem which I am facing is that I am not getting where I can upload those images(product images are getting stored in img/p, do I have to use the same directory).

Second issue is I am not getting how and where I can create functionality to show list in admin panel to manage.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what exactly you want to do. But if you want some Images in Frontend
you can create a CMS-Page and Upload your images via WYSIWYG Editor.

You can upload your images via backend or put them on your server via ftp/ssh
in an public folder and link them.

[image]